# What is the quickest way to check if user exists in a large table? (Performance Optimization)

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I'm working on a website with about 500,000 users, the issue im having is that when a user goes to create a new account the wait time is extremely long because i check if a user exists using this query.

```
select count(userName) as userNameTotal from user_table where userName = 'hellokitty'
```

I then decide if they can create account based on if the userNameTotal is greater then 0.

I was going to index the column but i think this would also be slow when it i try to add a user to the table, as the indexed column table will need to be recreated every time a user is added.

Is there a faster way to do this and should this column be indexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
select count(userName) as userNameTotal
from user_table
where userName = 'hellokitty'
```

You want an index on `user_table(userName)`.

However, this is not the most efficient approach.  You should keep the same index and use `exists`:

```
if (exists (select 1 from  from user_table where userName = 'hellokitty'))
begin 
 . . .
end;
```

This should be faster than the aggregation version, because it can stop at the first matching row.

Comment: The correct index would have the biggest impact on performance.  The use of `exists` is an additional gain on top of that.

Comment: but lets say yes they exist and then it goes to add the user. I feel then i would lose in performance because the username index, would need to be recreated every time i add a user. I guess what i'm saying is where would it be slower to have the index recreate and take a hit on performance when i add a user or having no index and taking a hit checking to see if the username exsist?

Comment: The index does not need to be recreated; a new element is added.  The index is usually faster, because the overhead to add an element is much, much less than the cost of doing a full table scan to read the table without an index.

Comment: okay thanks that is what i was wondering. so its more efficient to add an element to the columns index then to have a full table scan.

Comment: @LeslieJones For just one scan may no.  By in your application you are probably going to search on userName many many times.

Comment: It will be faster to update the index than it will be to scan the table.  You would also improve performance by setting the fill factor for the index to something other than 100%.  I would recommend 90%.  When you insert a row in to the table, SQL Server needs to update the index.  If there is enough room in page on the index, it is a simple (and quick) update.

Comment: @GMastros That is not correct.  An insert on fragmented index can take longer than a scan.